Do I need the parameters (armature current, field current etc) to do part 2?

I've completed the first part, but currently stuck on the second. Our lecturer didn't give us much to work with, so I felt completely lost trying to do this. I've been trying to complete this for a few days now.
I tried looking up datasheets for DC motors online, but I didn't have much to work with. (It's specified that if we use real-life applications, bonus marks will be given.)  This is one I was particularly keen on using, but had no idea how to calculate any of the power, speed, torque, and efficiency for the permanent magnet DC motor since I had no armature resistance, inductance, current etc, (I know it's given in the table, but we're expected to provide calculations).
I tried designing a MATLAB Simscape circuit, but again no luck since no parameters. I was even thinking of plugging in whatever values was given from the data sheets in MATLAB and comparing the data sheets rpm/time graphs with the one I've obtained and using the parameter estimation to get the remaining values, which seemed like a great idea until actually trying to find manufacturer rpm/time graphs. I'm completely lost on how I should thread forward with this assignment.
To summarize, I'm not sure if I even need the parameters to calculate what I need to calculate since most manufacturers don't provide it (if I don't, which formulas should I use?). I'm also not sure if I'm tackling this problem right, but I'll appreciate if someone will help and give their thoughts on how they would get started with the second part. Thanks.
